# Adding a directory to $PATH in CentOS?

Tags: centos, configuration, shell, root, path

We just got our new server(s) up and we're running CentOS on them all. After successfully installing Ruby Enterprise Edition, I would now like to add the REE `/bin` (located at `/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin`) directory to make it the default Ruby interpreter on the server.

I have tried the following, which only adds it to the current shell session:

```bash
export PATH=/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin:$PATH
```

What would be the correct approach to **permanently** adding this directory to `$PATH` for **all users**? I'm currently logged in as `root`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It's not a good idea to edit `/etc/profile` for things like this, because you'll lose all your changes whenever CentOS publishes an update for this file. This is exactly what `/etc/profile.d` is for:

```bash
echo 'pathmunge /usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin' > /etc/profile.d/ree.sh
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/ree.sh
```

Log back in and enjoy your (safely) updated `$PATH`:

```bash
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

which ruby
/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby
```

Instead of logging back in, you could reload the profile:

```bash
. /etc/profile
```

This will update the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: `~/.profile` is another valid option too

Comment: Yes, for a single user. But the question was about altering PATH for **all** users.

Comment: @Mike What is this pathmunge command?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov I'm pretty sure it just appends a path to $PATH.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov it a function that is defined in /etc/profile

Comment: No need to `chmod +x`; on my installation all other files in `/etc/profile.d` have `644`.

Comment: If anyone run into permission issue, surround your command with sudo sh -c "<command>" as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031443/2963280).

Answer (score 12):

After following fmonk's advice I checked out `/etc/bashrc`, where I noticed it said that "Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile." I proceeded to look in `/etc/profile`, I saw this:

```
pathmunge () {
    if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
       if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
          PATH=$PATH:$1
       else
          PATH=$1:$PATH
       fi
    fi
}

[...]

# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /sbin
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
fi
```

To solve my problem, I simply added `pathmunge /usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin` underneath the if statement. This solved my issue.

Comment: Could someone explain what the `"$EUID" = "0"` means in this context?

Comment: EUID 0 means that user is root.

Comment: You should have used /etc/profile.d. See my answer below.

Comment: Please consider accepting @MikeConigliaro answer as the correct. His way is the correct one. It's developed to work that way. Take a look at the files in `/etc/profile.d/` folder and you'll notice it. Also, as he said, a system update could undo your solution.

Answer (score 6):

SORRY misinterpretted the question
**the following asnwer is for a USER's profile**
leaving it in case it helps someone

modify .bash_profile

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then somewhere in the file add/modify your paths seperated by :

```
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/your/path
 export PATH
```

then reload your profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or logout and login again

if you check PATH it should include your newly added paths

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

> "An interactive login shell is started
>   after a successful login, using
>   /bin/login, by reading the /etc/passwd
>   file. This shell invocation normally
>   reads /etc/profile and its private
>   equivalent ~/.bash_profile upon
>   startup.
>
> An interactive non-login shell is
>   normally started at the command-line
>   using a shell program (e.g.,
>   [prompt]$/bin/bash) or by the /bin/su
>   command. An interactive non-login
>   shell is also started with a terminal
>   program such as xterm or konsole from
>   within a graphical environment. This
>   type of shell invocation normally
>   copies the parent environment and then
>   reads the user's ~/.bashrc file for
>   additional startup configuration
>   instructions." 
>   http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html

Therefore I would not put environment variables in bashrc, because it is not only against common convention, but you will also miss your bashrc varialbles when invoking a terminal from a graphical Desktop environment.

On Redhat in the `/etc/profile` I found this comment:

> "System wide aliases and functions should go in /etc/bashrc.  Personal
>   environment variables and startup programs should go into
>   ~/.bash_profile.  Personal aliases and functions should go into
>   ~/.bashrc."

So if you want to set environment variables on a user basis, do it in the user's .bash_profile file.

Heading over to the `.bash_profile` I read:

> "Personal environment variables and startup programs.
>
> Personal aliases and functions should go in ~/.bashrc.  System wide
>   environment variables and startup programs are in /etc/profile.
>   System wide aliases and functions are in /etc/bashrc."

**Conclusion** 
If you want only root to see programs residing, for instance in /`sbin` I would add that path to root's `.bash_profile` file. But if you want every user to see what root specific programs are installed on your box I would put `/sbin` into `/etc/.profile`. Now every user can use tab completion to look for root specific programs and elevate rights if necessary.

**Special Case: SSH**
When ssh is started with a commandline, an interactive login shell is started. But in this case `/etc/profile` is not read. When I defined environment variables in the `.bash_profile` file of each user it worked with ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables in a .rc file; for bash shells (I believe the most common, and default in CentOS) each user has a file called .bashrc in his home directory.

Add the command PATH=/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin:$PATH to this file to set it for any one particular user.

To set it for all users (as you mention), change it in /etc/bashrc (the default .bashrc in each user's home directory should source this file, but you should doublecheck that).

Answer (score 0):

Why does everyone forget about `/etc/environment`. Setting environment variables for all users is what this file is for.  Just add the name value pair of the environmental variable on one line. Don't use variables.

/etc/environment

```
PATH=:/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

This will add the directories `/usr/lib/ruby-enterprise/bin` `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH variable, for all users, once you logout or restart.

`/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` were already on my path before, but were removed for some reason after I edited this file. So add these two directories to be safe.